# Can “half an approximate hour” mean 27~29 minutes?

Tags: quantifiers

Can “half an approximate hour” mean 27~29 minutes? I want to know “approximate” is distinguished from “half.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally put  quantifiers in order least accurate to most accurate, so a native speaker would say "approximately half an hour".